custom Fields in Pipedrive
I'm really new to this. Can you tell me how I can obtain a list of all the custom fields and their contents? I need to understand what each code in the deals table represents.
I'm unsure which object contains the list of the custom fields' contents to establish the relation. Could you help me with this?
